# Geocoding multiple locations and check for closest to user

Tags: xcode, mapkit, geocoding

Im have an array of address strings that I need to geocode and see if the location is close the the users location. I only get the first address geocoded and the rest of them do not. I have a method that geocodes and checks the location vs the users location and adds the string to a NSMutable array. And Ideas??

```
[self findCloseShacks:[self.utahAddress objectAtIndex:0]];
[self findCloseShacks:[self.utahAddress objectAtIndex:1]];
[self findCloseShacks:[self.utahAddress objectAtIndex:2]];
```

this method geocodes and finds if it is within 10 km

```
      -(void)findCloseShacks: (NSString *)address
    {
     [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    }


        CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        tempLat = location.coordinate.latitude;
        tempLong = location.coordinate.longitude;

        CLLocationDistance meters = [myUserLocation distanceFromLocation: location];

        if(meters > 10000)
        {
            [closest addObject:address];
            NSLog(@"added %@", address);

            MKPointAnnotation *pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tempLat, tempLong);
            [pin setCoordinate:locCoords];
            NSArray *titles = [self.utahShackAndAddress allKeysForObject:address];
            NSString *theTitle = [titles objectAtIndex:0];
            [pin setTitle:theTitle];
            [self.mapview addAnnotation:pin];
    }

}];
```

}

Comment: That finds all shacks that are further than 10,000m away. Is that what you were hoping for?

Comment: yes, but It only checks for the object at index 0: none of the other ones. Ive tried the above code and using it in a for loop

Comment: You should show how you construct the utahAddress array and the output from the NSLog statement.